# Query fails when writing "group" column in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have a table (stitch) with one row, like this:

[image: table]

All columns are formatted as text.

when I run:

`SELECT * FROM stitch WHERE user='liam'`
I get the expected result of a single row.

But when I run:

`SELECT * FROM stitch WHERE group='010000'`
I get a syntax error. I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: can you share table structure screen short?

Comment: The group seems to be MySQL reserved word, try this : `SELECT * FROM stitch WHERE \`group\`='010000'`

Comment: or you can share syntax error, after running query by phpmyadmin or sql command prompt.

Comment: Taiki was correct. When I run "SELECT * FROM stitch WHERE `group`='010000'" it works. Since group is a command in mysql it was messing things up. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is because `group` is a keyword in MySql. So use rather:

```
SELECT * FROM stitch WHERE `group`='010000'
```

i.e. `group` inside **backticks(``)**.

Comment: actually it's called `backtick`